# How to advise a CL method?

Tags: advice, cl

I am familiar with setting advice on a function:

```lisp
(advice-add 'some-tag :before 'function-being-advised
    (lambda (arg)
        (message "In advice with arg: %s" arg)))
```

How do you advise a CL method on a class?

```
(cl-defmethod my-class-foo ((obj my-class-bar)) ...)
(cl-defmethod my-class-foo ((obj my-class-quz)) ...)
```

There are two `my-class-foo`.  If I do

```
(advice-add 'some-tag :before 'my-class-foo my-advice-func)
```

does that advise both methods? Neither?